# Creating trendline from non numeric data and fixing border on pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I am trying to create  a trendline using one column showing months. I would like it to count amount of cases that a product was bought in that month and show dependency between amount of bought products in a specific month. I know I could show it using barplot however I would much more prefer to do it with a line going through all months and creating peaks and lows in sales.

I was also trying to make a border around pie chart with this same data set but I can't find how can I make it to go around semgents of data not every single isntance.

Here is my code for trendline:

```
sprzed$W.jakim.miesiacu.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl.<-as.character(sprzed$W.jakim.miesiacu.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl.)
    sprzed$W.jakim.miesiacu.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl.<-factor(sprzed$W.jakim.miesiacu.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl., levels=c("Styczen","Luty","Marzec","Kwiecien","Maj","Czerwiec","Lipiec","Sierpien","Wrzesien","Pazdziernik","Listopad","Grudzien"))
    
    ggplot(sprzed, aes(x=W.jakim.miesiacu.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl., y=as.factor(Jakiej.marki.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl.))) + 
      geom_point() + 
      geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

For the pie chart:

```
p <- ggplot(sprzed, aes(x="",y="",fill=Jakiej.marki.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl.)) + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
      coord_polar("y", start=0)

    p + 
      geom_bar(stat="identity", color='black') +
      guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(colour=NA)))
```

[Here is how the pie chart looks like now:]
[image]

And my data:

```
structure(list(Sygnatura.czasowa = c("2020/11/29 5:05:05 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:05:31 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:05:54 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:06:10 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:06:23 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:07:12 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:08:00 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:08:17 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:08:21 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:08:36 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:08:51 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:09:34 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:10:10 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:10:27 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:10:47 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:10:56 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:11:11 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:11:20 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:11:50 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:12:00 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:12:18 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:12:21 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:12:53 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:13:17 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:13:20 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:14:02 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:14:25 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:14:42 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:14:43 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:15:05 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:15:07 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:15:22 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:15:37 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:16:17 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:16:33 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:16:46 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:16:50 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:16:50 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:17:11 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:17:12 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:17:20 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:17:43 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:17:57 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:17:59 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:18:35 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:18:51 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:18:53 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:19:09 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:19:26 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:19:32 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:19:45 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:19:50 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:19:50 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:20:26 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:20:36 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:20:39 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:21:07 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:21:09 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:21:30 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:21:54 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:22:28 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:22:30 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:22:45 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:22:46 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:22:47 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:23:02 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:23:22 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:23:38 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:23:40 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:23:58 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:24:14 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:24:18 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:24:41 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:24:58 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:25:06 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:25:25 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:25:48 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:25:54 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:27:21 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:27:48 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:28:20 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:28:21 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:29:06 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:29:08 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:29:57 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:30:08 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:30:29 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:30:55 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:30:56 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:31:08 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:31:17 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:31:25 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:31:57 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:32:16 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:32:32 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:32:45 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:33:01 PM CET", 
"2020/11/29 5:33:07 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:33:35 PM CET", "2020/11/29 5:33:55 PM CET"
), W.ktorym.roku.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl. = c(2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L, 2019L, 2020L, 2020L), Jakiej.jest.Pan...Pani.plci. = c("Kobieta", 
"Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", 
"Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Kobieta", 
"Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", 
"Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Mezczyzna", "Kobieta", "Mezczyzna"
), Jaki.jest.Pana...Pani.status.spoleczny = c("Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Bezrobotny", "Bezrobotny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Bezrobotny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Bezrobotny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Student", 
"Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Student", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Student", "Student", "Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Bezrobotny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Student", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Bezrobotny", "Student", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Bezrobotny", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Bezrobotny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Student", "Student", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", "Pracownik umyslowy", 
"Student", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", "Pracownik fizyczny", 
"Pracownik fizyczny"), Do.jakiej.grupy.wiekowej.Pan...Pani.nalezy. = c("18 - 25", 
"26 -35", "36 - 45", "46 - 55", "36 - 45", "56 - 65", "46 - 55", 
"36 - 45", "18 - 25", "46 - 55", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "26 -35", 
"26 -35", "> 65", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "36 - 45", "18 - 25", 
"46 - 55", "56 - 65", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "56 - 65", "18 - 25", 
"46 - 55", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", 
"46 - 55", "26 -35", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "46 - 55", 
"26 -35", "26 -35", "26 -35", "46 - 55", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", 
"26 -35", "26 -35", "46 - 55", "18 - 25", "56 - 65", "36 - 45", 
"18 - 25", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "36 - 45", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", 
"36 - 45", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "18 - 25", 
"36 - 45", "36 - 45", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "26 -35", "18 - 25", 
"18 - 25", "56 - 65", "36 - 45", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "26 -35", 
"26 -35", "26 -35", "36 - 45", "26 -35", "46 - 55", "26 -35", 
"26 -35", "26 -35", "18 - 25", "36 - 45", "36 - 45", "56 - 65", 
"18 - 25", "18 - 25", "26 -35", "36 - 45", "36 - 45", "26 -35", 
"46 - 55", "46 - 55", "46 - 55", "36 - 45", "18 - 25", "36 - 45", 
"46 - 55", "26 -35", "46 - 55"), Jaki.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl. = c("Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Nowy", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", 
"Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", 
"Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", 
"Nowy", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Nowy", 
"Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany", "Nowy", "Uzywany", "Uzywany"), 
    Jakiej.marki.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl. = c("Honda", "Honda", 
    "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", "Honda", "Harley Davidson", "Kawasaki", 
    "Junak", "Yamaha", "Romet", "Honda", "Kawasaki", "Bmw", "Suzuki", 
    "Harley Davidson", "Honda", "Honda", "Harley Davidson", "Suzuki", 
    "Bmw", "KTM", "Yamaha", "Junak", "Suzuki", "Suzuki", "Benelli", 
    "Honda", "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", "Honda", "Kawasaki", "Kawasaki", 
    "Bmw", "Honda", "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "KTM", "KTM", "Suzuki", 
    "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "Suzuki", "Yamaha", 
    "Benelli", "Yamaha", "Bmw", "Suzuki", "Romet", "Junak", "Yamaha", 
    "Suzuki", "Suzuki", "Honda", "Romet", "Yamaha", "Honda", 
    "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "Suzuki", "Benelli", "Junak", "Honda", 
    "Suzuki", "Honda", "Kawasaki", "Kawasaki", "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", 
    "Suzuki", "Suzuki", "Yamaha", "Kawasaki", "Yamaha", "Harley Davidson", 
    "Suzuki", "Honda", "Bmw", "Kawasaki", "Kawasaki", "Kawasaki", 
    "Romet", "Junak", "Yamaha", "Junak", "Yamaha", "Honda", "KTM", 
    "Kawasaki", "Romet", "Honda", "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "Honda", 
    "Honda", "Yamaha", "Yamaha", "Honda", "Honda"), Pana...Pani.motocykl.jest. = c("Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Kupiony w Polsce", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", 
    "Kupiony w Polsce", "Sprowadzony zza granicy", "Sprowadzony zza granicy"
    ), W.jakim.miesiacu.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl. = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 
    8L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
    7L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 10L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 10L, 4L, 
    3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 11L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 
    9L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 
    1L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 1L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
    7L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("Styczen", "Luty", "Marzec", "Kwiecien", "Maj", 
    "Czerwiec", "Lipiec", "Sierpien", "Wrzesien", "Pazdziernik", 
    "Listopad", "Grudzien"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = "data.frame")
```

I will be really thankful for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the Pie chart problem here is how I did it:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

 mypalette<-brewer.pal(10,"RdYlBu")
      
    ggplot(sprzed, aes(x=factor(1), fill=factor(Jakiej.marki.kupil.Pan...Pani.motocykl.))) + 
      geom_bar(width=1, color="black") + 
      scale_fill_manual("Marka motocykla",values = mypalette)+
      coord_polar("y", start=0)+
      theme(text = element_text(size=24),
            axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
            axis.title.y=element_blank(),
            axis.text.y=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.y=element_blank()
            )
```